# A subgroup of multiplicative group of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I can't seem to find a solution to this:

Let $ K $ be a field of characteristic not equal to $ 2 $, $ K^* $ be its multiplicative group and $ K^{*2} = \{k^2, ~ k\in K^*\}$

Prove that if $ a \notin K^{*2} $ then for the set $ H_a = \{x^2 - ay^2; ~ x,y \in K\} $ we have that

$ K^{*2}\neq H_a \neq K^*$

Well, of course $ K^{*2} \neq K^* $. I was trying to prove that if

$ \forall_{x,y} x^2 - ay^2 = c^2 $ for some $ c $, then $ a $ is a square, but all that I got is that $ a= (x/y)^2 - (c/y)^2 $

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^{*2} = \mathbb{C}^*$, although presumably you are working with the hypothesis that there exists an $a \notin K^{*2}$.

Comment: Of course, my forgotten assumption was that $ K $ is a fraction field of the ring $ O_p $ of $ p-$adic integers. I'm almost done with the solution, I'll post it sometime soon